# Singular value of a partitioned matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

all.

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be a matrix partitioned as $\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{X}_{1} \\ \mathbf{X}_{2} \end{bmatrix}$.

I want to lower bound the smallest singular value $\sigma_{\min}(\mathbf{X}_{1})$ using $\mathbf{X}$. Is there any relationship between $\sigma_{\min}(\mathbf{X}_{1})$ and $\mathbf{X}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is badly written.

$X_1\in M_{p,n},X_2\in M_{q,n}$. We assume that $p+q\geq n$.

$X^*X=X_1^*X_1+X_2^*X_2\geq X_1^*X_1\in M_n$.

$X$ has $n$ singular values, but $X_1$ has $\min(p,n)$ singular values; if $p\leq n$, then we put the $n-p$ supplementary singular values of $X_1$ equal to $0$.

Then $\sigma_{min}(X_1)\leq \sigma_{min}(X)$ (upper bound).